# requests are 95% faster just for commenting a print statement?

Tags: rust, concurrency, request

[main-reference rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-02-message-passing.html#:%7E:text=a%20chat%20message.-,Filename%3A%20src/main.rs,-use%20std%3A%3Async)

the modified code for above program listed is

```
fn main() {
    let (tx1, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        tx1.send("hi2").unwrap();
    });

    let mut count = 0;

    loop {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(msg) => {
                println!("{:?}", msg);
                break;
            }
            Err(_) => {
                // println!("not yet");
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    print!("{:?}", count)
}
```

if i commented out the println statement the count is approx above 1646 as its varying everytime but it is around 10-20 if its not commented out
can someone please explain why

update1: as per the comments i tried replacing println with `std::io::stdout().write(b"not yet").unwrap();` and the count is around 350-380
and if im using this instead `let mut buffer = std::io::BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout()); buffer.write(b"not yet").unwrap();` the count is around 82
so my final question is does it matter like the number of requests per second

Comment: Each execution of `print` individually acquires a lock on `stdout`, pipes the output, then releases the lock. This locking and unlocking is expensive.

Comment: @PitaJ, Are you so sure that it isn't writing the console that takes up so much time? IDK rust, but in every other programming language that I have used, locking and unlocking an uncontested mutex rarely ever takes any significant amount of time.

Comment: Usually, printing is a, comparatively, slow operation. It's usually particularly obvious when you print in a loop. This is do to how buffering / flushing works. You can increase significantly the performance by not flushing for each print operation, by wrapping stdout with [BufWriter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) for example.

Comment: It's a combination of locking, piping, flushing, and releasing. You can do microbenchmarks if you want, but all that matters here is that at least part of that operation is slow. I would be interested in seeing `print!()` statements (even with "\n" allowed since I think you need to explicitly flush with a `print!()` statement even if it includes "\n") and a manual flush at the end

Comment: This is a very bizzare "benchmark" since this is basically a measure of how long it takes for the spawned thread to start and send the message which is not based on time, but rather the "count" of calls to `try_recv` vs `try_recv`+`println`. This does not mean you're receiving the message any faster, just you're doing more work while waiting for it.

Comment: @kmdreko ye i agree with you that the no of calls might be more when we are not using println but in general for example for some large data or for something big just for reference if the no of calls per second is slow then the program might also be slow right?

Comment: @PitaJ [and as others said as im unable to tag others] i used buffwriter and its approx around 350-380 range

Comment: For an older trick, try it where it writes to the console (default), and then run it again while redirecting the output to a file ("program_name > output.txt").  It'll be far faster.  So while the fact you're doing I/O of course matters, the fact that it goes to a real console can matter even more.

Comment: @ninetynin It is very hard to understand what exactly you're asking. If its because *"can someone please explain why"*, then that's been answered in the comments that `println` is much more expensive than a simple integer increment and so you can loop less times before the message arrives. Or if the question is *"does it matter"*, then sure if you do more work between checking for the message then that will delay acting on that.

Comment: But your code and these questions seem like XY problems. Are you trying to time how long it takes to receive a message? There's other, better ways to do that. Are you trying to receive the message as fast as possible? Then just do `rx.recv()`. Are you trying to optimize the performance of printing to stdout? There's even better ways than what's even mentioned here.

Comment: @kmdreko i was just curious as printing makes the compile time slow in very less ignorable amount but like does it ever matter... ig its not that important and can you please share any links or like suggest the better ways that u were saying about.. im complete beginner to using multithreading and channeling stuff

Comment: *"printing makes the compile time slow"* are you sure you mean *compile time* or do you mean *run time*? I'll assume you mean run-time and in most cases you shouldn't really worry about the costs of printing unless you're in a performance critical section where you might avoid prints or if a significant portion of the program is producing output.

Comment: And the improvement I alluded to is acquiring the `StdoutLock` *once* and putting that in a `BufWriter` would give you the best performance of printing a lot of data in sequence. Though that will prevent prints in other threads to potentially be blocked for a long period of time, but like I said I would only encourage that if your program's goal is to produce a lot of output. And that doesn't seem the case in the above example where its dubious that you're looping and printing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bit of a conceptual misunderstanding here, your `count` code isn't measuring what you think it is measuring.  Naturally, printing out to the console is more expensive than incrementing a variable, but it doesn't make a big difference in the actual execution time of your program.

It appears you are trying to measure how much time your main thread is waiting in the loop to receive a message from the second thread that you spawn. Let's say that it takes `N` microseconds on average for your second thread start up after you've spawned it and send a message (there's actually the potential for a lot of variance here, as it depends on operating system scheduling and system loading). Does it really matter what your main thread is doing during those `N` microseconds you are waiting for a message? You're either printing to the console and/or incrementing your counter, but either way, your main thread is waiting until it receives the message.

To show this, you can measure time elapsed like so:

```
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let (tx1, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        tx1.send("hi2").unwrap();
    });

    let mut count = 0;

    let t1 = std::time::Instant::now();
    loop {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(msg) => {
                println!("got message: {:?}", msg);
                break;
            }
            Err(_) => {
                // delta doesn't change much if this print is commented out
                println!("not yet"); 
                count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    let t2 = std::time::Instant::now();
    let delta = t2-t1;
    
    println!("time: {}", delta.as_micros());
    println!("count {}", count)
}
```

If you run this code multiple times with and without the `println!()` in the loop commented out, you will see that although `count`'s value will differ, the `delta` time will not differ very much.

Comment: You could even comment out both the `println!()` and the `count += 1` in the loop and see that the `delta` doesn't really change.